# Angular 2 ng bootstrap typehead pass additional parameter

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How to pass form array index to getCities function in ng-bootstrap typehead including current input text. Consider **3** is form array index.

**address.component.html**

```
<input name="city" type="text" id="city" formControlName="city" [ngbTypeahead]="getCities">
```

**address.component.ts**

```
getCities = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(query =>
        query.length < 2 ? [] : this.apiService.getCities(query).catch(() => {
            return Observable.of([]);
        });)
```

Comment: Check the "wikipedia example" of the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you are needing to pass an additional parameter to the ngbTypeahead function (be it an index parameter or otherwise).

While the documentation ( https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api ) does not provide for passing parameters, you can implement a "factory" method that returns an appropriate function with the index (or whatever) parameter passed in.

**address.component.html**

```html
    <input name="city" 
        type="text" 
        id="city"
        formControlName="city"
        [ngbTypeahead]="searchFunctionFactory($index)" >
```

**address.component.ts**

```js
    //A function that returns a "search" function for our ngbTypeahead w/ "preloaded" parameters
    public searchFunctionFactory($index: any): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]> {


        //Create a function that considers the specified $index parameter value
        let getCities = (text$: Observable<string>) => 
            text$
                .debounceTime(300)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .switchMap( query => {

                    //some logic involving $index here
                    //...

                    //query.length < 2 ? [] : this.apiService.getCities(query).catch(() => {
                    //return Observable.of([]);
                });

        //Return that "custom" function, which will in turn be called by the ngbTypescript component
        return getCities;
    }
```

Comment: as of the current docs, this is the correct answer. Be sure however to call the correct method from the dom `[nbgTypeahead]="branchSearchFactory($index: any)"`

Comment: @ScottClark I corrected my example: `[nbgTypeahead]="searchFunctionFactory($index: any)`
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand your example. I didn't see where $index was defined or set so it answered the question above. Please can you expand?

Comment: The example given assumed that the `<input>` tag is inside of a `NgForOf` template, being repeated. 
See https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables
That said, "$index" could be anything. For example, perhaps you want your `nbgTypeahead` to only search across that have a length of `numChars`. Somewhere else in your app (the component, a template variable, etc.) you would need to set up a variable called `numChars` and then you would pass it to your own search function factory function(e.g., `buildSearchFunctionWhichLimitsStringsTo(numchars: number)`)

Comment: Seems this is currently broken, see https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4055