# Angular 4 ng bootstrap typehead pass additional parameters

Tags: ng-bootstrap

with reference of [Angular 2 ng bootstrap typehead pass additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314751/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-typehead-pass-additional-parameter/48450745#48450745)

I have address.component.html

```
<input name="city" type="text" id="city" formControlName="city" [ngbTypeahead]="getCities">
```

and address.component.ts as

```
getCities = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(query =>
    query.length < 2 ? [] : this.apiService.getCities(query).catch(() => {
        return Observable.of([]);
    });)
```

My requirement is I want to use getCities for two different text controls based on some parameter like [ngbTypeahead]="getCities('domestic', 'us')". Based on the response provided in thelink referenced above, $index can be passed as [nbgTypeahead]="branchSearchFactory($index: any)". But if I try to pass some variable I'm getting JavaScript compilation error.

So can we pass variables in [ngbTypeahead]?
 Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit? What is your problem Statement?

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: Did you ever solve this?