# ngbTypeahead - Pass parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using ngbTypeahead for typeahead search functionality, but I am wondering if I can pass parameters to the search function.

```
<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search(param1, param2)"/>
```

Angular

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap(() => (this.searching = true)),
  switchMap(term =>
    this.underwritingServiceWrapper.search(term).pipe(
      tap(() => (this.searchFailed = false)),
      catchError(() => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
        return of([]);
      })
    )
  ),
  tap(() => (this.searching = false))
)
```

I have checked this, but it seems not working.
[Angular 2 ng bootstrap typehead pass additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314751/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-typehead-pass-additional-parameter)

Can someone help me with an example?

Answer (score 3):

The `ngbTypeahead` input is supposed to be a function that takes an observable of string as argument and returns an observable of array or results. I.e. it must be of type `(text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]>` (as the api doc indicates).

Your code would be fine if `search` was a method taking two parameters and returning returned such a function:

```
search(param1: SomeType, param2: SomeOtherType): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<any[]> {
  return (text$: Observable<string>) => text$.pipe(
    ...
  );
}
```

But it isn't that. I'm not sure what you want to achieve here. Maybe you simply need to use `this.param1` and `this.param2` into your function:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    // use this.param1 and this.param2 here 
  );
```

Comment: I have managed to make this work when i used **Observable<{}>**              Code: `search(param1: SomeType, param2: SomeOtherType): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<{}> {.....}` however `Observable<any[]>` is throwing this error.

Comment: That means that search() returns an Observable<{}> instead of an Observable<Array<Something>>. You ned to fix that method.